# echoprint codegen for Java/Android

Tags: java, android, c, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

Is there a way to run the echoprint-codegen on Android or is there a Java implementation for it?

Echoprint codegen on github: https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-codegen

There is a C++ implementation for it? I just cannot figure out how to port it to Java so that I can run it on an Android device, assuming Android 2.2 and up.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Alex Restrepo's port of Echoprint to Android.  His blog posting with the technical details is here:

http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/

The complete code along with a sample Android application using it can be found here:

https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid

Answer (score 3):

Try this open source project by Jacquet Wong, it's written in Java and Android compatible.

http://code.google.com/p/musicg/

It handles wave spectrogram, fingeprint and other audio features with FFT and other dsp algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

There are java libraries to deal with FFT / Audio which may already do what you need. 
Ropy van Rijn already did this,  and got slap from Shazam patent holders.

See in detail:
http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

I will try to look here:
http://developer.echonest.com/
and then here:
http://developer.echonest.com/client_libraries.html
and after that you have downloaded the java client, this:
https://gist.github.com/1630910
could be useful (sorry is italian code, but im sure you won't have problem)